# How to prevent element not to be edited from listB and to be edited from listA if listA = List.from(listB) in flutter?

Tags: android, list, flutter, dart

In flutter, I have two lists, and the code is as below. I changed one element from ListA but it also get changed from ListB, why does this happen??

```
List<Model> listA = List(),
        listB = [
          new Model.withData(value: "b1"),
          new Model.withData(value: "b2")
    ];
    listA = List.from(listB);
    print("listA:" + listA.toString() + "   listB:" + listB.toString());
    listA[0].value = "a1";
    print("listA:" + listA.toString() + "   listB:" + listB.toString());
```

this gives output as

```
 listA:[Model{value: b1}, Model{value: b2}]   listB:[Model{value: b1}, Model{value: b2}]
 listA:[Model{value: a1}, Model{value: b2}]   listB:[Model{value: a1}, Model{value: b2}]
```

How to change element only from ListA and not from ListB??

This is my Model class

```
class Model{
  String value;
  Model.withData({this.value});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Model{value: $value}';
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are copying objects from listB to listA so in both lists, list items refer to same objects and as you make change in object, it effects on both lists.

> for(var model in listB){
>       listA.add(new Model.withData(value:model.value)) 
> }

Try such approach i hope, it would be helpful.